# Cannot assign a class variable to a given value

Tags: python, oop

The code:

```
class YouTubeDownloader:
    ID=0
    Title =" "
    Description= " "
    PublishedAt =" "
    def IDFetch(self):
        IDRequest = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+self+"&key="+APIKey+"&part=snippet"
        if len(list(self))==11:
            Data =requests.request(url=IDRequest,method="Get")
            Data = Data.json()
            ID= Data['items'][0]['id']
            self.ID = ID
        else:
            print("Wrong ID")
```

However, I cannot assign the self.ID to the given value ID, it's giving the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/x/red/simple.py", line 78, in <module>
    Data =YouTubeDownloader.IDFetch("jB8Vp1tgdbo")
  File "/home/x/x/red/simple.py", line 21, in IDFetch
    self.ID = ID
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ID'
```

Comment: You need to show how you are calling this method. Do you actually have an instance of the class?

Comment: I don't understand what you are pointing out. Sorry, I'm relatively new to python.

Comment: I'm not pointing out anything. I'm asking you to show the code that calls this.

Comment: I was using a static method to call the function
like: YoutubeDownloader.METHODNAME()

Comment: Well then why are you trying to set instance variables?

Comment: My bad, I was totally clueless. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `IDFetch` as a static method:

```
Data =YouTubeDownloader.IDFetch("jB8Vp1tgdbo")
```

Instead, you have to create an instanze of `YouTubeDownloader` before calling methods:

```
class YouTubeDownloader:
    ID=0
    Title =" "
    Description= " "
    PublishedAt =" "
    def IDFetch(self, video_id):
        IDRequest = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+video_id+"&key="+APIKey+"&part=snippet"
        if len(list(video_id))==11:
            Data =requests.request(url=IDRequest,method="Get")
            Data = Data.json()
            ID= Data['items'][0]['id']
            self.ID = ID
        else:
            print("Wrong ID")

downloader = YouTubeDownloader()
data = downloader.IDFetch("jB8Vp1tgdbo")
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
self.ID = ID
```

Place:

```
YouTubeDownloader.ID = ID
```

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to do this?